# Como obtener los clientes que no han tenido compras en este año

Tags: sql-server

que tal.
Tengo una tabla de clientes y una tabla facturas, de las cuales quiero obtener los clientes que no han hecho compras en este año, alguien me podría ayudar. He investigado y me sallio que usando el "not in" o el "not exists" pero no logro el resultado deseado.
Esta es la consulta que tengo hasta ahora

```
SELECT f.NumCliente
FROM Facturas AS f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NumCliente FROM Facturas WHERE YEAR(Fecha) = '2023')
```

Todavía sigo viendo otras páginas para ver si lo logro.

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla para clientes? deberías partir de ahí. Si no, es como pedir que "levante la mano quien no está".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás confundiendo un poco la sintaxis entre `IN` y `EXISTS`. Otro detalle importante, es que necesitas tomar los clientes de tu tabla de Clientes, de otra forma podría estar incompleta la lista y además puede haber duplicados.

Para poder utilizar `EXISTS` necesitas relacionar la subconsulta con la consulta principal.

```
SELECT *
FROM Clientes AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Facturas f
                  WHERE c.NumCliente = f.NumCliente
                  AND   Fecha >= '20230101'
                  AND   Fecha <  '20240101');
```

Otra opción puede ser con `NOT IN` que funciona casi igual (siempre y cuando no haya nulos en la subconsulta).

```
SELECT *
FROM Clientes AS c
WHERE c.NumCliente NOT IN (SELECT f.NumCliente 
                           FROM Facturas f
                           WHERE Fecha >= '20230101'
                           AND   Fecha <  '20240101');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me funciono mejor la segunda opcion con **NOT IN**

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el operador <> / es indiferente, no igual a. Supongo que la forma en que sabes que un cliente no tiene compras es si no tiene facturas, entonces creo que sería algo así. Y creo que los alias los tienes demás si es solo es esa consulta.

```
SELECT f.NumCliente
FROM Facturas AS f
WHERE fecha <> '2023';
```

Comment: Eso solo traerá clientes con facturas que tengan fecha distinta al primero de enero de 2023.